# How to have app send message to Microsoft Teams via Graph API?

Tags: node.js, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I want to be able to use the graph API to get a list of channels & teams, then have the app send an update to the appropriate channel without the user having to interact with MS Teams.  Looking around I see a lot of posts saying this isn't possible yet, but [Monday.com](https://support.monday.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010359819-Microsoft-Teams-Integration?source=search) and [Smartsheet](https://www.smartsheet.com/marketplace/apps/microsoft-teams) seem to be doing this. Monday.com even specifies its using the beta api and *neither* are using connectors.

I attempted to do use the api `POST /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages` after authenticating via the way [shown in this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service)

First Call for `adminconsent`

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminconsent?&client_id={botID}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://myoauthCallback&scope=offline_access User.ReadWrite.All Group.ReadWrite.All`

After that returns I do an immediate call to get an access token, the above call doesn't seem to return anything I need to put into this request.

`POST => /organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token`

`body = client_id={botId}&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret={secret}&grant_type=client_credentials`

I set the permissions in `https://portal.azure.com/#blade/` for the bot to have the same scope as the first request above. Here it doesn't like the scope passed in the same way so I set it to `default`

I then take the `access_token` that is returned and attempt the call to `POST` a message to the channel.

URL: `/teams/{TEAM_ID}/channels/{CHANNEL_ID}/messages`

body: `{
        subject: 'test subj',
        body: { contentType: 'text', content: 'Test message from app' },
      }`

This results in an error

`statusCode: 401, code: 'UnknownError', message: ''`

So how do I get the same functionality of these other apps so I can send a message directly to teams without setting up a connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Turns out it was a Office 365 Connector vs the regular "connector" that requires configuration within teams.</s>

<s>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EqodWkS5PYM</s>

Edit: Disregard, even with office 365 connectors it requires the user to still interact with MS Teams in some way.

Another Edit: Turns out it is using Proactive Messaging https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#net-example-from-this-sample

Although technically you cannot actually send a message to the app without a user interacting with the bot first, the installation of the app does trigger a conversationUpdate to which you can reply. So In the end, I can install the Teams app, and send a bot notification all within my web app, without the user having to actually touch Microsoft Teams.

Comment: I am trying to use this API to post a message to the channel but I end up receiving a 401 response, can you please tell me how you go it to work ? I'm not sure I understood your answer here. I have granted several application and delegated permissions to my App (including the required ones) but I continue to receive 401, the request body is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the "auth" page [you linked to](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service), it's talking about creating Application permissions. However, see the ["create chatMessage in a channel"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) graph documentation and under "permissions" near the top it shows that it supports "Delegated" permissions only, so you can't use that particular endpoint with Application permissions unfortunately.

Connectors (Webhooks) will be able to do what you need, but you say you want to avoid that - perhaps you can explain why it's not ideal? I'm not aware of how to create a webhook programmatically, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thats the big limitation, it can't be done automatically. I know that the way I'm going about it is incorrect, I just cant figure out the correct way. I know that the above example apps from monday.com and smartsheet are *not* using connectors, and instead the graph api. So its possible, I'm just not sure how

Comment: Can I ask how you  know this directly? I certainly couldn't see anything on the Monday.com link you sent about it. Perhaps they're doing the first part using the graph api, but doing the send of the message itself via a webhook?

Comment: I don't have concrete proof, but webhooks are essentially an alias for connectors correct. They show up in a channel's "Connectors" menu and need to be configured?  With the above apps nothing shows in the channels configured connectors list, and no configuration is needed on the Teams side.  Monday.com also specifies its using the Teams Graph Beta features, which connectors are not a part of. 

Is there a way to programmatically create a webhook that isn't a teams connector?